# Submitting checkboxes with jquery and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, checkbox

So I have this form with a table in a php page:

```
$page .='<form method="POST" action="delete.php" ID="orgForm">';
$page .= "<table> \n";
$page .= "<tr>\n";
//Decides what to display based on logged in. Only if logged in can you see all the contact's info
$page .= "<th>ID</th> \n <th>First Name</th> \n <th>Last Name</th> \n <th>Phone Number</th> \n <th>Email</th> \n";
//Loops through each contact, displaying information in a table according to login status
$sql2="SELECT cID, firstName, lastName, phoneNum, email FROM Contact WHERE oID=".$_GET['orgID'];
$result2=mysql_query($sql2, $connection) or die($sql1);
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_object($result2))
{
    $page .= "<tr>\n";
    $page .= "<td>".$row2->cID."</td>\n";
    $page .= "<td>".$row2->firstName."</td>\n";
    $page .= "<td>".$row2->lastName."</td>\n";
    $page .= "<td>".$row2->phoneNum."</td>\n";
    $page .= "<td>".$row2->email."</td>\n";
    $page .= '<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkedItem[]" value="'.$row2->cID.'"></input></td>'."\n";
    $page .="</tr>";
}
$page .= '<input name="deleteContacts" type="submit" value="Delete Selected Contacts" />'."\n";
$page .= "</form>\n";

$page .='<script src="assets/js/orgDetails.js" type="text/javascript"></script>'."\n";
```

I need to somehow write an jquery script inside orgDetails.js that is able to delete the checked rows when I push delete button. The change have to appear on screen without refresh, and I also need to be able to delete the actual row from the sql db as well. Can someone please give me a hand? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In action url delete.php, After submit this post:

```
if ($_POST != array()) {
    foreach ($_POST['checkedItem'] as $id) {
        mysql_query('delete from Contact where cID='.$id);
    }

    echo 'Records deleted.';
}
```

If you dont want page refresh when delete records:

Add to html:

```
<button class="delete_button">Delete selected records</button>
```

Add your js file:

```
$('.delete_button').click(function () {
    $form = $('#orgForm');

    delete_ids = [];

    $form.find('input[name=checkedItem]').each(function () {
        $checkbox = $(this);

        if ($checkbox.is(':checked')) {
            delete_ids.push($checkbox.val());
        }
    );

    $.ajax({
        url: 'delete.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {delete_ids: delete_ids},
        success: function (result_html) { alert(result_html); },
    });
});
```

And in delete.php:

```
if ($_POST != array()) {
    foreach ($_POST['delete_ids'] as $id) {
        mysql_query('delete from Contact where cID='.$id);
    }

    echo 'Records deleted.';
}
```